# Cannot restart Apache?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I just installed Apache from homebrew (brew install httpd).

When i try to restart it with the command :

```
 sudo apachectl --restart
```

I get this message :

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using daniel.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (pid 40659) already running
```

Only way i can really restart Apache is by restarting the machine...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried **sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart** (or wherever you installed it to)

Comment: Also there is `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @davidmneedham This returns me the error 'sudo: service: command not found'

Comment: Surround text with backticks to obtain ``monospace text``

Comment: @delphirules Did you try my way as well? Can you find where apache2 is actually located?

Comment: @EricF It seems now i have 2 Apache installations on my machine, one in '/etc/apache2' and other in '/private/etc/apache2'. When i run 'which apachectl' on terminal, it gives me '/usr/local/bin/apachectl'. I'm totally lost !

Comment: @delphirules Have you tried both `sudo /etc/apache2 restart` and `sudo /private/etc/apache2 restart`?

Comment: @EricF How can i know what Apache is running, the /etc or the /private/etc ?

Comment: `which apache2` but really if you try to restart either of the two above you might find that one works and the other doesn't

Comment: @ericf 'which apache2' gives me a blank result...'which apachectl' gives me '/usr/local/bin/apachectl'

Comment: Try also `which apache` and `which httpd`

Comment: @EricF 'which http' gives me '/usr/local/bin/httpd'

Comment: httpd is the name of the apache service.  Which is the reason the error mentions the service returning the error is httpd by the way.  So have you set ServerName?

Answer (score 1):

For the **Brew** version of Apache (httpd) it is installed in the `/usr/local` tree.  You can find the `httpd.conf` file at `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

In the `httpd.conf` there is a directive called `ServerName` and the default config is:

```
#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:8080
```

Uncomment the `ServerName` and specify a fully qualified hostname.

Other host names can be defined in `VirtualHosts` as needed.

If you are not using ports in the protected range you do not need to use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error code, but was able to resolve it following the XAMPP Path Setup instructions available from [How to Install XAMPP on MacOS and configure a path for PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyCWVwxy8aA).

If you watch the video, the instructions to do this are about halfway through. I added the lines of code to the top of the profile file, as instructed, then the error message went away.

I restarted the mac (note: to start the Apache Web Server in XAMPP, I first had to run the following code in terminal as there was a conflict with multiple versions `sudo apachetl stop` - you can start again with `sudo apachetl start` if needed), then I started the Apache Web Server on XAMPP. All is working well.

Reference to start, stop or restart Apache:  [Stop, start, or restart Apache 2 Web Server from terminal on Mac OS](https:////drupalsun.com/gulab-bisht/2018/11/14/start-stop-or-restart-apache-2-web-server-terminal-mac-os)

(Note: Using Mac OS Ventura)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).